# My DQN for a FlappyBird made with pygame in python Don't learn

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, pygame, reinforcement-learning

I created a DQN which learn to play a FlappyBird made with pygame, but my problem is that when i run the code it seams that th DQN don't learn, the loss not decreasing and the bird don't achieve to pass the first pipe.
I already tried to change some of th hyperparameters but nothing change, i change the leearning rate, i tried to decrease the learning rate through the time. I tried to increase : the update of the target weight, the size of the replay memory, the batch size.
I think tthat the problem can comme from thee flappyBird but I don't see what can i change.

**main.py**

```
# Import Libraries

import pygame
import sys
from FlappyBird import FlappyBird
import math
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import namedtuple
from itertools import count
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torchvision.transforms as T


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Deep Q-Network

class DQN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_features=9, out_features=20)
        self.out = nn.Linear(in_features=20, out_features=2)

    def forward(self, t):
        t = F.relu(self.fc1(t))
        # t = F.relu(self.fc2(t))
        t = self.out(t)
        return t


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Experience class

Experience = namedtuple(
    'Experience',
    ('state', 'action', 'next_state', 'reward')
)


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Replay Memory

class ReplayMemory:
    def __init__(self, capacity):
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.memory = []
        self.push_count = 0

    def push(self, experience):
        if len(self.memory) < self.capacity:
            self.memory.append(experience)
        else:
            self.memory[self.push_count % self.capacity] = experience
        self.push_count += 1

    def sample(self, batch_size):
        return random.sample(self.memory, batch_size)

    def can_provide_sample(self, batch_size):
        return len(self.memory) >= batch_size


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Epsilon Greedy Strategy

class EpsilonGreedyStrategy:
    def __init__(self, start, end, decay):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.decay = decay

    def get_exploration_rate(self, current_step):
        return self.end + (self.start - self.end) * math.exp(-current_step * self.decay)


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Reinforcement Learning Agent

class Agent:
    def __init__(self, strategy, num_actions, device):
        self.current_step = 0
        self.strategy = strategy
        self.num_actions = num_actions
        self.device = device

    def select_action(self, state, policy_net):
        rate = strategy.get_exploration_rate(self.current_step)
        self.current_step += 1

        if rate > random.random():
            action = random.randrange(self.num_actions)
            return torch.tensor([action]).to(device) # explore
        else:
            with torch.no_grad():
                return policy_net(state).argmax(dim=1).to(device)  # exploit


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Environment Manager

# FlappyBird.py


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Progression Graph

def plot(values, moving_avg_period):
    plt.figure(2)
    plt.clf()
    plt.title('Training...')
    plt.xlabel('Episode')
    plt.ylabel('Score')
    plt.plot(values)

    moving_avg = get_moving_average(moving_avg_period, values)
    plt.plot(moving_avg)
    plt.pause(0.001)
    print("Episode", len(values), "\n", moving_avg_period, "episode moving avg :", moving_avg[-1])


def get_moving_average(period, values):
    values = torch.tensor(values, dtype=torch.float)
    if len(values) >= period:
        moving_avg = values.unfold(dimension=0, size=period, step=1).mean(dim=1).flatten(start_dim=0)
        moving_avg = torch.cat((torch.zeros(period - 1), moving_avg))
        return moving_avg.numpy()
    else:
        moving_avg = torch.zeros(len(values))
        return moving_avg.numpy()


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Tensor processing

def extract_tensors(experiences):
    batch = Experience(*zip(*experiences))

    t1 = torch.cat(batch.state)
    t2 = torch.cat(batch.action)
    t3 = torch.cat(batch.reward)
    t4 = torch.cat(batch.next_state)

    return t1, t2, t3, t4


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


# Q-Value Calculator

class QValues:
    device = torch.device("cpu")

    @staticmethod
    def get_current(policy_net, states, actions):
        return policy_net(states).gather(dim=1, index=actions.unsqueeze(-1))

    @staticmethod
    def get_next(target_net, next_states):
        final_state_locations = next_states.flatten(start_dim=1).max(dim=1)[0].eq(0).type(torch.bool)
        non_final_state_locations = (final_state_locations == False)
        non_final_states = next_states[non_final_state_locations]
        batch_size = next_states.shape[0]
        values = torch.zeros(batch_size).to(QValues.device)
        values[non_final_state_locations] = target_net(non_final_states).max(dim=1)[0].detach()
        return values


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


# Main Program

FIRST_TIME = True  # True if this is the first time you run this code

batch_size = 128
gamma = 0.999
eps_start = 1
eps_end = 0.01
eps_decay = 0.000001
target_update = 3000
memory_size = 500000
lr = 0.0005
num_episodes = 500000
weight_save = 100
lr_update = 500

device = torch.device("cpu")
strategy = EpsilonGreedyStrategy(eps_start, eps_end, eps_decay)
agent = Agent(strategy, 2, device)
memory = ReplayMemory(memory_size)

policy_net = DQN().to(device)
target_net = DQN().to(device)
target_net.eval()
optimizer = optim.Adam(params=policy_net.parameters(), lr=lr)

if FIRST_TIME:
    torch.save(optimizer.state_dict(), "./Optimizer_weight/weight.pt")

optimizer.load_state_dict(torch.load("./Optimizer_weight/weight.pt"))

score = []

if FIRST_TIME:
    target_net.load_state_dict(policy_net.state_dict())
    torch.save(policy_net.state_dict(), "./Policy_weight/weight.pt")
    torch.save(target_net.state_dict(), "./Target_weight/weight.pt")

policy_net.load_state_dict(torch.load("./Policy_weight/weight.pt"))
target_net.load_state_dict(torch.load("./Target_weight/weight.pt"))

pygame.mixer.pre_init(frequency=44100, size=16, channels=1, buffer=512)
pygame.init()

em = FlappyBird()

for episode in range(num_episodes):

    em.start_game(em)

    state = torch.tensor([em.get_state(em)]).to(device).float()

    while True:
        action = agent.select_action(state, policy_net)
        reward, next_state = em.step(em, action)
        reward = torch.tensor([reward]).to(device).float()
        next_state = torch.tensor([next_state]).to(device).float()
        memory.push(Experience(state, action, next_state, reward))
        state = next_state

        if memory.can_provide_sample(batch_size):
            experiences = memory.sample(batch_size)
            states, actions, rewards, next_states = extract_tensors(experiences)

            current_q_values = QValues.get_current(policy_net, states, actions)
            next_q_values = QValues.get_next(target_net, next_states)
            target_q_values = (next_q_values * gamma) + rewards

            loss = F.mse_loss(current_q_values, target_q_values.unsqueeze(1))
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

        if em.is_done(em):
            score.append(em.get_score(em))
            plot(score, 100)
            print("Exploration : ", round(strategy.get_exploration_rate(agent.current_step) * 100), "%")
            if memory.can_provide_sample(batch_size):
                print("Loss : ", loss.data)
            break

    if episode % target_update == 0:
        target_net.load_state_dict(policy_net.state_dict())
        torch.save(target_net.state_dict(), "./Target_weight/weight.pt")
        print("Target Updated")

    if episode % weight_save == 0:
        torch.save(policy_net.state_dict(), "./Policy_weight/weight.pt")
        torch.save(optimizer.state_dict(), "./Optimizer_weight/weight.pt")

    if episode % lr_update == 0:
        lr = lr * 0.995
        print("Learning Rate : ", lr)

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

**FlappyBird.py**

```
# Imports
import pygame
import sys
import random
import math


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Game Class

class FlappyBird:

    def __init__(self):

        self.pipe_is_spawned = False

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((576, 1024))
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.game_font = pygame.font.Font('Flappy bird assets/04B_19.TTF', 60)

        # Games Variables
        self.gravity = 0.6
        self.bird_movement = 0
        self.game_active = False
        self.score = 0
        self.high_score = 0
        self.speed = 100

        self.bg_surface = pygame.image.load('Flappy bird assets/sprites/background-day.png').convert()
        self.bg_surface = pygame.transform.scale2x(self.bg_surface)

        self.floor_surface = pygame.image.load('Flappy bird assets/sprites/base.png').convert()
        self.floor_surface = pygame.transform.scale2x(self.floor_surface)
        self.floor_x_pos = 0

        self.bird_downflap = pygame.transform.scale2x(
            pygame.image.load('Flappy bird assets/sprites/bluebird-downflap.png')).convert_alpha()
        self.bird_midflap = pygame.transform.scale2x(
            pygame.image.load('Flappy bird assets/sprites/bluebird-midflap.png')).convert_alpha()
        self.bird_upflap = pygame.transform.scale2x(
            pygame.image.load('Flappy bird assets/sprites/bluebird-upflap.png')).convert_alpha()
        self.bird_frames = [self.bird_downflap, self.bird_midflap, self.bird_upflap]
        self.bird_index = 0
        self.bird_surface = self.bird_frames[self.bird_index]
        self.bird_rect = self.bird_surface.get_rect(center=(100, 512))

        self.BIRDFLAP = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
        pygame.time.set_timer(self.BIRDFLAP, 800)

        self.SPEEDUP = pygame.USEREVENT + 2
        pygame.time.set_timer(self.SPEEDUP, 40000)

        self.pipe_surface = pygame.image.load('Flappy bird assets/sprites/pipe-green.png').convert()
        self.pipe_surface = pygame.transform.scale2x(self.pipe_surface)
        self.pipe_list = []
        self.SPAWNPIPE = pygame.USEREVENT
        pygame.time.set_timer(self.SPAWNPIPE, 2400)
        self.pipe_height = [525, 550, 600, 650, 675]
        self.point_collider = pygame.Surface((10, 300))
        self.point_collider.set_alpha(0)
        self.collider_list = []

        self.game_over_surface = pygame.image.load('Flappy bird assets/sprites/message.png').convert_alpha()
        self.game_over_surface = pygame.transform.scale2x(self.game_over_surface)
        self.game_over_rect = self.game_over_surface.get_rect(center=(288, 512))

        self.flap_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('Flappy bird assets/audio/wing.wav')
        self.death_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('Flappy bird assets/audio/die.wav')
        self.hit_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('Flappy bird assets/audio/hit.wav')
        self.point_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('Flappy bird assets/audio/point.wav')

        self.rewardMultiplier = 1
        self.INCREASEREWARD = pygame.USEREVENT
        pygame.time.set_timer(self.INCREASEREWARD, 2400)

    @staticmethod
    def draw_floor(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.floor_surface, (self.floor_x_pos, 900))
        self.screen.blit(self.floor_surface, (self.floor_x_pos + 576, 900))

    @staticmethod
    def create_pipe(self):
        random_pipe_pos = random.choice(self.pipe_height)
        bottomPipe = self.pipe_surface.get_rect(midtop=(700, random_pipe_pos))
        topPipe = self.pipe_surface.get_rect(midbottom=(700, random_pipe_pos - 300))
        point_collider_rect = self.point_collider.get_rect(midbottom=(700, random_pipe_pos))
        return bottomPipe, topPipe, point_collider_rect

    @staticmethod
    def move_pipes(self, pipes, colliders):
        for pipe in pipes:
            pipe.centerx -= self.speed
        for collider in colliders:
            collider.centerx -= self.speed
        return pipes, colliders

    @staticmethod
    def draw_pipes(self, pipes, colliders):
        for pipe in pipes:
            if pipe.bottom >= 1024:
                self.screen.blit(self.pipe_surface, pipe)
            else:
                flip_pipe = pygame.transform.flip(self.pipe_surface, False, True)
                self.screen.blit(flip_pipe, pipe)

        for collider in colliders:
            self.screen.blit(self.point_collider, collider)

    @staticmethod
    def check_collision(self, pipes):
        for pipe in pipes:
            if self.bird_rect.colliderect(pipe):
                self.hit_sound.play()
                return False

        if self.bird_rect.top <= -100 or self.bird_rect.bottom >= 900:
            self.death_sound.play()
            return False

        return True

    @staticmethod
    def check_pipe_reached(self, colliders):
        for collider in colliders:
            if self.bird_rect.colliderect(collider):
                colliders.remove(collider)
                self.pipe_is_spawned = False
                return colliders, True
        return colliders, False

    @staticmethod
    def rotate_bird(self, bird):
        new_bird = pygame.transform.rotozoom(bird, -self.bird_movement * 2, 1)
        return new_bird

    @staticmethod
    def bird_animation(self):
        new_bird = self.bird_frames[self.bird_index]
        new_bird_rect = new_bird.get_rect(center=(100, self.bird_rect.centery))
        return new_bird, new_bird_rect

    @staticmethod
    def score_display(self):
        score_surface = self.game_font.render(str(self.score), True, (255, 255, 255))
        score_rect = score_surface.get_rect(center=(288, 100))
        self.screen.blit(score_surface, score_rect)

    @staticmethod
    def is_done(self):
        if not self.game_active:
            self.pipe_is_spawned = False
        return not self.game_active

    @staticmethod
    def get_score(self):
        return self.score

    @staticmethod
    def start_game(self):
        self.game_active = True
        self.pipe_list.clear()
        self.collider_list.clear()
        self.bird_rect.center = (100, 512)
        self.bird_movement = 0
        self.score = 0
        self.speed = 4
        self.pipe_is_spawned = False

    @staticmethod
    def check_event(self, action):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if action == 1:
                self.bird_movement = 0
                self.bird_movement -= 15
                self.flap_sound.play()

            if event.type == self.SPAWNPIPE and self.game_active:
                bottom_pipe, top_pipe, win_collider = self.create_pipe(self)
                self.pipe_list.append(bottom_pipe)
                self.pipe_list.append(top_pipe)
                self.collider_list.append(win_collider)
                self.pipe_is_spawned = True

            if event.type == self.BIRDFLAP:
                if self.bird_index < 2:
                    self.bird_index += 1
                else:
                    self.bird_index = 0

                self.bird_surface, self.bird_rect = self.bird_animation(self)

            if event.type == self.SPEEDUP and self.game_active:
                if self.speed < 8:
                    self.speed += 0.05

            if event.type == self.INCREASEREWARD and self.game_active:
                self.rewardMultiplier += 0.01

    @staticmethod
    def is_game_active(self):
        # Bird
        self.bird_movement += self.gravity
        rotated_bird = self.rotate_bird(self, self.bird_surface)
        self.bird_rect.centery += self.bird_movement
        self.screen.blit(rotated_bird, self.bird_rect)
        self.game_active = self.check_collision(self, self.pipe_list)
        collider_list, pipe_reached = self.check_pipe_reached(self, self.collider_list)
        if pipe_reached:
            self.point_sound.play()
            self.score += 1

        # Pipes
        pipe_list, collider_list = self.move_pipes(self, self.pipe_list, self.collider_list)
        self.draw_pipes(self, pipe_list, collider_list)

        self.score_display(self)

    @staticmethod
    def draw_frame(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.bg_surface, (0, 0))

        if self.game_active:
            self.is_game_active(self)
        else:
            self.screen.blit(self.game_over_surface, self.game_over_rect)

        # Floor
        self.floor_x_pos -= 4
        self.draw_floor(self)
        if self.floor_x_pos <= -576:
            self.floor_x_pos = 0

        pygame.display.update()
        self.clock.tick(60)

    @staticmethod
    def get_reward(self):
        point = 0.1 * self.rewardMultiplier

        if not self.check_collision:
            point = -100 * self.rewardMultiplier
        elif self.check_pipe_reached:
            point = 50 * self.rewardMultiplier

        return point

    @staticmethod
    def get_state(self):
        if self.pipe_is_spawned:
            position = [self.bird_rect.centery, self.collider_list[0].centerx, self.collider_list[0].centery, math.sqrt((self.collider_list[0].centerx - self.bird_rect.centerx) ** 2 + (self.collider_list[0].centery - self.bird_rect.centery) ** 2), self.collider_list[0].centery - self.bird_rect.centery, self.collider_list[0].centerx - self.bird_rect.centerx, self.bird_movement, 900 - self.bird_rect.bottom, 900 - self.collider_list[0].centery]
        else:
            position = [self.bird_rect.centery, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 900 - self.bird_rect.bottom, 50, self.bird_movement]

        return position

    @staticmethod
    def step(self, action):
        self.check_event(self, action)
        self.draw_frame(self)

        point = self.get_reward(self)

        self.is_done(self)

        position = self.get_state(self)

        return point, position
```

Answer (score 0):

I’d say try adding another layer to your model architecture first, because it’s very small. Also, the observations your receiving from that environment have some very large integers, so you might want to normalize each of those features. Another suggestion that is unrelated is that it is more efficient to implement the replay buffer using a queue mechanism from `collections.deque(maxlen)`.

Comment: Thank you man, i have done all of the changes that you said and it is training now i will see if it's better now. I have one more question, are my rewards good ? and if not what is a good reward ?